# Converting local datetime values to UTC datetime values in SQL Server and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime-conversion, postgresql-13

I am trying to understand the behavior of `AT TIME ZONE` and I get some strange behavioral differences between SQL Server and PostgreSQL in this regard.

For demonstration purposes I produced two queries, one for SQL Server and one for PostgreSQL.

The SQL Server query:

```sql
SELECT
  [LocalTime],
  [LocalTime] AT TIME ZONE 'W. Europe Standard Time' AS [LocalTimeWithOffset],
  ([LocalTime] AT TIME ZONE 'W. Europe Standard Time') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS [UniversalTime]
FROM
  (VALUES
    (CAST('2020-06-20 12:34:56.789' AS DATETIME2)),
    (CAST('2020-12-20 12:34:56.789' AS DATETIME2))) AS [X] ([LocalTime])
```

produces this result (in SQL Server Management Studio):

```
LocalTime                    LocalTimeWithOffset                 UniversalTime
---------                    -------------------                 ----------------
2020-06-20 12:34:56.7890000  2020-06-20 12:34:56.7890000 +02:00  2020-06-20 10:34:56.7890000 +00:00
2020-12-20 12:34:56.7890000  2020-12-20 12:34:56.7890000 +01:00  2020-12-20 11:34:56.7890000 +00:00
```

which seems fine to me, since I live in the Netherlands: in the summertime, we are 2 hours ahead of UTC (due to daylight saving) and in the wintertime we are only 1 hour ahead of UTC.

BUT... the PostgreSQL query:

```sql
SELECT
  "LocalTime",
  "LocalTime" AT TIME ZONE 'WET' AS "LocalTimeWithOffset",
  ("LocalTime" AT TIME ZONE 'WET') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS "UniversalTime"
FROM
  (VALUES
    (timestamp '2020-06-20 12:34:56.789'),
    (timestamp '2020-12-20 12:34:56.789')) AS "X" ("LocalTime")
```

produces the following result (in pgAdmin):

```
LocalTime                    LocalTimeWithOffset         UniversalTime
timestamp without time zone  timestamp with time zone    timestamp without time zone
---------------------------  ------------------------    ---------------------------
2020-06-20 12:34:56.789      2020-06-20 14:34:56.789+02  2020-06-20 12:34:56.789
2020-12-20 12:34:56.789      2020-12-20 13:34:56.789+01  2020-12-20 12:34:56.789
```

which seems incorrect to me.

After struggling with this for a little while, I came up with another PostgreSQL query, which seems to yield the same results as the SQL Server query:

```sql
SELECT
  "LocalTime",
  "LocalTime"::timestamptz AS "LocalTimeWithOffset",
  "LocalTime"::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS "UniversalTime"
FROM
  (VALUES
    (timestamp '2020-06-20 12:34:56.789'),
    (timestamp '2020-12-20 12:34:56.789')) AS "X" ("LocalTime")
```

But this query seems to be dependent on the PostgreSQL server's time zone. :-(

Is there any (preferably elegant) way to mimic the SQL Server logic/behavior in PostgreSQL without a dependency on the server's time zone (and use an explicitly specified time zone in the query)?

**Edit**

I am aware that it is a good practice to store UTC date/time values in the database and convert them (preferably in/by the client) to local date/time values when presented to end users. I am intending to do so as well, of course, but my current scenario is a database migration from SQL Server to PostgreSQL (as part of a big application overhaul), where the `DATETIME2` table columns in the SQL Server database contain local date/time values, which I want to convert to UTC date/time values in corresponding `timestamp` columns in the PostgreSQL tables. My migration script will work fine with the queries above, so actually I do not have a blocking issue. The reason for this question is that I am just curious about the apparent differences between SQL Server and PostgreSQL regarding the `AT TIME ZONE` behavior and the ways to overcome those behavioral differences.

Comment: What is your `timezone` setting?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . Executing `SHOW TIMEZONE` in PostgreSQL gives the value `CET`. I guess that is not the correct time zone...

Comment: Well, the display of a `timestamp with timezone` is determined by your setting of `timezone`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . Ah yes. I think I know what you mean. Values of type `timestamp with time zone` do not contain time zone information. Such values are simply stored internally as UTC date/time values. When executing the query `SELECT timestamptz '2020-12-20 12:00:00+02', timestamptz '2020-12-20 14:00:00+04'` for example, I would get the values `2020-12-20 11:00:00+01` and `2020-12-20 11:00:00+01`. Completely different behavior compared to SQL Server's `DATETIMEOFFSET` data type. I will look into this somewhat more. Perhaps changing the `TIMEZONE` setting makes my last query "configurable".

Comment: I would say that `timestamp with timezone` works differently in PostgreSQL than in other databases. I suspect that trying to make them behave the same will fail, and you will have to take a broader view.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . Yes, I agree. I made some wrong assumptions regarding the behavior of PostgreSQL here. I will continue to investigate it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql, `AT TIME ZONE` allows time zones to be added to date/time values that lack them (TIMESTAMP WITHOUT  TIME ZONE, ::timestamp), and allows TIMESTAMP WITH  TIME ZONE values (::timestamptz) to be shifted to non-local time zones and the time zone designation removed.

So, in the first query you've written for postgres, you're trying to cast `'2020-06-20 12:34:56.789'` to timestamp, and you've applied `AT TIME ZONE` on it for `LocalTimeWithOffset`. This is the case where postgres considered the input as timestamp in UTC and converted to the corresponding time zone, in your case `WET`, which is `UTC+2:00` in Summer and `UTC+1:00` in winter.

Now, in the third case, you're first applying the `AT TIME ZONE 'WET'` to timestamp `'2020-06-20 12:34:56.789'`, hence the input is considered as `UTC` and converted to `WET`, the output is `timstamptz`, and this output is then fed again to `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`, so as per behavior of `AT TIME ZONE`, it gets converted to `UTC` and the timezone tag is removed, which is, the input we given.

So, AT TIME ZONE did not behaved weird in `postgresql` rather did exactly what it was supposed to do, according to the [documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)

Hope your confusion is cleared.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm still confused. I do understand your explanation, but I fail to understand why applying `AT TIME ZONE` in the second column of my first query assumes that the input as timestamp is in UTC... It's just a `timestamp` value and I want to indicate that it's a WET time zone value, not a UTC time zone value. How should I accomplish that? (As you said in the first paragraph, in PostgreSQL, `AT TIME ZONE` should allow time zones to be added to date/time values that lack them (TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, ::timestamp). As far as I can see, that's the case here.)